# using client side validation with telerik controls

Tags: validation, telerik, controls

Can you use client side validation with telerik controls?  The examples show validation using standard html input controls.  I have forms with RadTextBoxes, RadComboboxes etc and would like to add validation.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should post more specific question, try something and show your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the Telerik client-side api by using

```
var ctrl = $find('<%= txtSomeTextBox.ClientID %>');
```

then you can get the current value of the textbox by calling the .get_value() function. Use your browser's debug tool to see which methods are available in the object that is returned or consult Telerik's help site.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Telerik's online demos: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/input/examples/common/validation/defaultcs.aspx and you will find examples for almost anything. This one shows how to use the built-in client-side validation with the RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX.